# asp.mvc returns wrong view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have code like this:

```
public ActionResult Verification(string quarter, long employeeId)
{
    var consents = VerificationQueries.ClientsConsents(employeeId, CurrentSession, report.Quarter);
    var mifidsFund = VerificationQueries.ClientsMifidsFund(employeeId, CurrentSession, report.Quarter);
    var mifidsMak = VerificationQueries.ClientsMifidsMak(employeeId, CurrentSession, report.Quarter);

    var model = new VerificationViewModel(report, consents, mifidsFund, mifidsMak);
    if (quarter == "12016")
    {
        return View("Verification_12016", model);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Verification", model);
    }
}
```

quater can have 2 values: "12016" and "22016".
In debugger server returns both Views but browser allways renders "Verification_12016" View.
What is the problem?

edit:
I changed View names for: "Verification_12016" and "Verification_22016" and works correct.But what is the problem, that I can't have ""Verification" View?

Comment: Are you using the output cache?

Comment: do you have [OutputCache] enabled for this action or controller? If it were ignoring the quarter parameter, that would cause it.

Comment: how to check is OutputCache is enabled? Id don't have any atributes like this in controller.

Comment: Have you stepped through to make sure that both code paths run successfully?

Comment: Yes. I step both code paths in debugger. Now I changed view names for: Verification_12016 and Verification_22016 and this works ok, but what is the problem with "Verification" View name?

Comment: @zchpit I am having the same problem, I have a view with the name `_Login` and `_LoginManager` and it always returns `_LoginManager`, that's so weird. Only after changing the name it works properly.

Comment: @OffirPe'er I suppose that this can be internal framework issue correlated with fluent API. In my case using _ was the fastest option to deliver working solution before deadline and I don't analized this problem in depth ;-)